# Gradle dependency management for micro service projects

Tags: java, gradle, dependency-management

We are currently using gradle as a build tool. We use the micro services architecture so let's say we have project A, version 1 that generates A-v1.jar. Project B, version 1 is dependent on project A and other jars and produces B-v1.jar. Project C, version 1 is dependent on B and other jars and produces C-v1.jar.

Now when we upgrade project A, version 1 to version 2, we want all the downstream dependencies to also upgrade as appropriate.

Currently we do this manually and we looked at BOM but that seems to just provide another level of indirection but not really solve this issue.